# Android Error when setting text on EditText

Tags: android-edittext

I attempting to set the text on an EditText in code but receive the following error:-

> java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.LinearLayout cannot be cast to android.widget.EditText

I have several edits texts which setText correctly, this one is on a LinearLayout nested on a parent LinearLayout. So I have

```
LinearLayout1
     EditText1   >- Set text works ok
       Nested LinearLayout2
          EditText2  >-  Find elements works ok but setText fails with the error above.
```

I have tried setting target as LinerLayout1 and 2 (c is an index in a loop of children)

The code snipit is as follows:-

```
View tmp = target.getChildAt(c);
EditText et = (EditText) target.getChildAt(c);
//et correctly resolves as the correct EditText
String s = "[some value]";
et.setText(s);  << this throws the above error
```

Answer (score 0):

have you tried using?

```
    EditText et = (EditText) (EditText) this
            .findViewById(R.id.EditText2);
```

while having in your layoutfile

```
    <EditText android:id="@+EditText2/" .../>
```

if you are using

```
     int c=5;
     this.getChildAt(c);
```

you are getting the 5th elemenet in the curent layout hirarchy. 
that may also work but is quite uncommon and fragile. if you later change the layout you also
have to update the code.

Comment: All my views are being created dynamically so the Id is unknown, The getChildAt(c) is used because I have already looped through the controls to find the one I want to update and this one is at index (c). I have tried the above code with the same results, again the et resolves correctly to the EditText, in debug I can see properties correctly such as hint text, but once I try to setText it throws the same error.